# People without a minimum number of up-voted questions of their own should be restricted from flagging or suggesting edits to other's questions

Tags: discussion, questions, flags, suggested-edits

I think people only **answering** questions sometimes lack empathy with people **asking** questions since they are seldom in that situation.

I use "empathy", deliberately, as distinct from "sympathy". With "empathy", one understands a person's motivation, but does not necessarily agree with it or feel sorry for them. With "sympathy", one agrees with, supports, or feels sorry for someone. Whether an editor/flagger sympathies with someone is irrelevant, but understanding (empathizing with) them seems like an inherently good idea.

I think it may be useful to require users to have asked at least one up-voted question, so that they can more fully appreciate that side of the relationship, before they are granted the privilege to flag, suggest edits, etc. This does not seem like a big hurdle to overcome.

Do you think this analysis is correct? Please express your agreement or disagreement in your comments and answers.

Comment: Can you explain why you are asking for this? What's the benefit? Why doesn't it outweigh the cost (did you consider the cost)?

Comment: Um... why? I've only asked like two questions on average on the sites I visit... that doesn't mean I can't possibly know what makes a good question.

Comment: Someone who never asked a question can't recognize a spam post? Why would that be?

Comment: As the answerer on some sites, this bugs me. Why I can't flag a question if it's unclear/too broad? And why should I ask a question, if the answer often can be found already, and I don't have any issue currently?

Comment: @David what do you think of my edit? Your previous edit only made the question worse in my opinion. I tried to make some sense out of your proposal. Please let me know if I understood you right.

Comment: You are, once again, modifying your question to ask something different.  Don't do that.

Comment: No.  You had a feature request.  Which you've now changed into something entirely different.  If you have a different question, use the Ask Question button.  Modifying your question, especially after an answer, is just going to get rolled back.

Comment: Yes.  The problem is that you are changing your question entirely.  You're free to continue to do so, but chances are extremely good it's just going to get rolled back.  Again.  If you want to ask a question about empathy, *ask a new question*.  **Don't modify an existing one with an answer to ask something completely different**.

Comment: No, users have downvoted because they *disagree* with your feature request.  Votes on meta are different, as you have been made well aware.  By changing the entire question, you're not improving anything; you're just forcing two sets of votes onto a single question, none of which is going to be an accurate indicator of the existing question.  When you've already got an answer, too, you're doing a disservice to the answerer, because they're no longer answering your original question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think this is a really bad idea. I had about 2000 reputation when I asked my first question on SO, and although I can be considered a high-rep user, I only have three questions. (or what about [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=topactivity). His ratio is 34 questions on 32K answers. He must be a very unsympathetic person)

Do you think someone like me didn't have enough empathy or sympathy because I didn't ask a question? Of course, we could force someone to ask a question and I am sure that wouldn't be a problem to gain a single vote on it.

The problem is: there is no correlation between having 'asking experience' and the quality or sympathy of that user. Or why wouldn't he be able to identify spam, or a low quality or unclear question?

Comment: @David I don't understand why you think empathy is only possible if you've asked a question... particularly requiring that you have asked a question on **that site** specifically. My highest-rep site is English Language Learners... And I'm certainly not a learner, so I have no reason to ask a question there but I certainly can answer them... But I know when/why a question is bad or off topic, so why shouldn't I be able to do my part in closing those questions.

Comment: @David [Voting is different on meta.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) Votes on feature requests are *supposed* to be in part an indicator of agreement/disagreement, and it's perfectly OK to downvote a well-written feature request if you don't support the request.