# Is the purpose of downvoting a question to get the questioner to change the question?

Tags: discussion

Is the purpose of downvoting a question to get the questioner to change the question?

Comment: You really should stick to one question per question.  Just as a heads-up.  Also, could you clarify your last point a bit?  The only scenarios I know that a user can't edit their *own* content is if they're banned from editing for a bit.

Comment: On meta downvotes also mean disagreement. And discussions on downvoting have been posted before a couple of times. If you really think you have something new to add you might want to include which earlier posts brought you to this set of ideas. Lastely it looks like you are asking about a specific post but for some reason choose to not make that public. In general users here don't like *that* kind of theoretical meta-talk.

Comment: @rene I don't know this user or the reasons for anything he does, but one of the difficulties of asking on meta is the need to provide specifics. I feel that users should be able to post in ways that don't open their actions up for public scrutiny, rather than being chastised for it. No need to respond, as that would take this post in a different direction. I just thought I'd mention it. Thanks.

Comment: [Context](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260367/is-asking-questions-a-good-indication-of-empathy-with-other-question-askers)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying

Comment: thanks to the context from @fbueckert I can see that you were totally in an edit war on that question. Changing it so dramatically is not an appropriate edit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is the purpose of downvoting a question to get the questioner to change the question?

It's not *the* purpose of downvotes.  One of many purposes of downvotes is an incentive for the author to improve the post.  Downvotes also:

- Are a signal to other users that the post isn't worth their time.
- Is a signal to automated system tools (i.e. the question ban) that the post is of low quality.
- It is a signal of the value of a post to determine whether a post can be deleted, how quickly it can be deleted, whether it'll be deleted automatically (and when), etc.
- Are a signal that the post is so bad as to merit immediate manual deletion by users.

> If so, should the questioner be allowed to change the question to try to get the downvoters to revert those votes?

The author can improve their question such that it will be of higher quality, yes.  They can't just replace the question with a completely different question, no.

> Should editors be allowed to roll back the questioner's such attempted edits?

Yes.  They might be harmful to the post.  The author doesn't have the right to vandalize their own content; and their attempts to do so will get rolled back.

> If a questioner has been caught in such a situation and is prevented by the community from either editing or deleting the question, what should be the recourse, if any?

The only thing that would prevent them from editing their own post is it being locked, and there are only two reasons to do this:

1. The post is no longer appropriate for the stie, but it's of significantly large value to the community anyway.  This is only considered for posts with *lots* of upvotes, so a user not being able to improve a low quality post isn't an issue.
2. Temporarily when there is some form of edit war going on, extensive discussions in comments, etc.  Note that in addition to preventing edits, it also prevents votes.  And again, these are always temporary, to give the users involved time to cool down; you can still prepare an edit to apply when the lock expires.

Comment: *"One of many purposes of downvotes is an incentive for the author to improve the post."* Nice, i've never seen downvotes considered as an incentive.

Answer (score 8):

> Is the purpose of downvoting a question to get the questioner to change the question?  If so, should the questioner be allowed to change the question to try to get the downvoters to revert those votes?

In a way, yes; the motivation here is that the question itself is either unclear or not useful, and it should be corrected in some way.  The hover text for the downvote reads as thus:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

Then again, since votes are anonymous and can be arbitrary, one could downvote for any reason they wanted to.  But the guiding principle is that the question has to change to make it more desirable.

The questioner usually *does* change the question to make it more answerable in certain cases; a downvote doesn't instantly lock the question or anything like that.  If one person downvotes but another sees that the question has *greatly* improved, someone may feel that it's worth an upvote at that point in time.

> Should editors be allowed to roll back the questioner's such attempted edits?

Only if the question is substantially less clear than the first attempt, or the question was vandalized in some way.  Otherwise, no.  If you see scenarios like that, flag for moderator attention.

Answer (score 6):

No, no, no.

The downvotes might convince the OP to change the question post, but that is not why there are downvotes. If you downvote a question, it means that the question is poorly asked/formatted, lacks a lot of research, you dislike the feature-request (that's only for metas), or for some other reason mentioned in the Help Center.

If you hover over the downvote button on any question, there will be a tooltip that tells you why someone would downvote a question. But remeber, downvotes might ***convince or make*** the OP change his question. Nothing else.

And rollbacks should only be used if the previous form of the question is more clear and/or better than the newer form of the question.

Answer (score 3):

Motivations are hard to determine on the SE network. Despite that, most of the guidelines I go by depend on motivation. To tackle your 4 subquestions at once is tricky, especially since some seem to depend on false premises, but I will try.

> Is the purpose of downvoting a question to get the questioner to change the question?

That is one purpose, yes. There are others: to warn readers not to even click on the question, to work towards getting the question off the front page, and to tell the questioner not to ask a question like that again.

> If so, should the questioner be allowed to change the question to try to get the downvoters to revert those votes?

A questioner is **always** allowed to change the question, in the sense of fixing flaws in it. You shouldn't change to an entirely unrelated question or make a change that invalidates answers, but clarifying something that was unclear or adding something that was missing is not just allowed, it's actively encouraged. Most downvoters never come back and revert their votes, but other people often give upvotes to improved questions.

> Should editors be allowed to roll back the questioner's such attempted edits?

Rolling back is **always** allowed. It's appropriate when someone has made a vandalizing change (such as replacing the entire question text with "blah blah blah" or a rant about how awful SE people are) or a radical change that invalidates answers that have already been added. If you object to a rollback, you can flag the post and a moderator can decide what should be done.

> If a questioner has been caught in such a situation and is effectively prevented by the community from either editing (by rollbacks) or deleting the question, what should be the recourse, if any?

If you're in an edit war, flag. You can also @-reply an editor and ask them why they made that change to the post. These sorts of situations can vary wildly and there is no single rule about when editing is ok, when rolling back is ok, and so on. That's why flagging for moderator attention is a good approach.

You could also post here with a link to the question and ask meta people to explain what's going on.

Comment: How many types of wars is there anyways?

Comment: @PythonMaster: Wikipedia would have an article on that very subject if it hadn't gotten caught in an AfD-war... (I am only about half kidding.)